# dynamic jquery image gallery isn't work on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have two divs with 'gallery' class (the required plugin's class) using jquery on the ReactJS rendering. The first was made by handwork code and it is working perfectlly. The second was generated dinamically by a loop concatenating variables, strings and tags  tags. In the second div - the thumbnails' images and its respective href (the enlarged image version) is appering in the screen perfectlly but its animation isn't working. Does anybody know how to solve it?

The function being called below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL_INTERIORES)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ interiores: res.data })
      })    

    $(function () {
      $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();      
    });        
  }
```

The React's rendering:

```
return (
      <div>

        // NOTE: This Gallery is working succefully.

        <div className="gallery">
          <a href="../images/int_02.jpg" className="big">
            <img src="../images/int_02_thumb.jpg" alt=""/>
          </a>
          <a href="../images/int_02.jpg" className="big">
            <img src="../images/int_02_thumb.jpg" alt=""/>
          </a>
          <a href="../images/int_02.jpg" className="big">
            <img src="../images/int_02_thumb.jpg" alt=""/>
          </a>
        </div>

        /*
        NOTE: This dinamic galley is showed but here isn't 
              the animation working.
        */                       

          {this.state.interiores.map(item =>
          <div>
          <div className="gallery">
            {
            item.fotos
              .map(foto =>
                <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">                       
                   <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                </a>
              )
            }

          </div>
     </div>
  )}
```

Comment: Please never ever ever use jQuery with React. It totally defeats the purpose and power of using React. With React you can just throw all of jQuery out of your project code. There are plenty of react image gallery available out there, just use one of them
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery , https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery , 
https://neptunian.github.io/react-photo-gallery/
and lot more

Comment: Thank you I will try your suggestions iin future projects but  I want end this project with this jquery library. I wasted a lot of time testing different things. If i get a new thing i will have new problems.

Comment: can you show any error message of console?

Comment: No there isn't any error message of console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I put the same function body of `componentDidMount()` inside of
`componentDidUpdate()` too. Now it is working succefully.

```
    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(URL_INTERIORES)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ interiores: res.data })
      })    

      $(function () {
        $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();      
      });        
    }

  // Here is the new code insertion: 

  componentDidUpdate() {
    $(function () {
      $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();      
    });
  }
```